# On page load redirect to the same page with querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi so i am getting a cookie passed in from another website which brings in some data i need to put in the query string.. i know how to put it in the query string that's not my questions.

My question is what jquery function can i use onpage load which will redirect to the query string.. now i don't want to page to load twice i want this to happen and look like it has only loaded once. I have tried to use a .one jquery but that's not needed anymore as the if statement will validate if the query string needs to change. Also that function is not working correctly anyway.

```
$(document).one('load', function() {
            if (window.location.pathname == '/items.aspx'){
            window.location.replace("items.aspx?item1=a80af972-4f78-de11");
            }
            });
```

any ideas would be great.
Thanks

Comment: location.href = "your path" will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.location.href="items.aspx?item1=a80af972-4f78-de11"`but that will also reload the page. Depending on your users internet  connection it **could** seem like one page load.

Another thing worth noting: You are waiting for `$(document).on("load")` which gets fired when the page is **loaded** which is exactly what you don't want.

Try this for speed increase:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if (window.location.pathname == '/items.aspx'){
        window.location.href = "items.aspx?item1=a80af972-4f78-de11";
    }
});
```

Still - this is a thing to do on the server side. Something in the backend like "if item1 is undefined load item a80af972-4f78-de11" would be best.

Comment: is there no way to do this before the page loads?

Comment: Not with JavaScript on the client side which has to be loaded in order to be executed. You could do a .htaccess or IIS-whatever redirect.